# AccessToKeyVaultDenied error when trying to read a secret from a key vault

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I have an Azure Key-Vault that uses the Role Based Access Control (RBAC). In this key vault I have a secret that I am trying to inject into a Function App.

In the key vault I have the following settings in the IAM:

[image: IAM settings in KV]

In addition, in the IAM settings of the secret itself, I have the following:

[image: IAM settings in the KV]

Lastly, in the Function App itself I defined an application setting that has the value `@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://kv-fuxxxnd.vault.azure.net/secrets/nile-estate-test-key/f63cxxxxxx5b2)`. However, I get the error `AccessToKeyVaultDenied`:

[image]

Any hints how to solve this? I read that I need to grant `LIST` and `GET` permissions for my app, but it doesn't seem to work because the key vault uses the RBAC approach. What is missing?

Comment: Check if this [article](https://medium.com/geekculture/troubleshooting-azure-key-vault-references-in-azure-function-apps-b228c1216f63) helps.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @PravallikaKV! Unfortunately, I already found this ref, and it didn't help. What seems to be the solution there is to add the IP of the function App to the firewall of the vault. However, my Vault already has `Allow public access from all networks` selected in the `Networking` section.

Comment: Check the below provided solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have followed below steps to achieve your requirement.

- I have created Function App with App Service Plan.
- Enabled System Assigned Identity in the `Function app=>Settings=>Identity`.
- Created Key Vault with RBAC access:

[image]

- I have assigned below Roles to the key vault:

```
1. Owner
2. Key Vault Administrator
3. Key Vault Certificates Officer
```

[image]

- Given ***Owner access to the function app in the Key Vault***.
- Created secret in Key Vault:

[image]

- Added the key vault reference as the application setting in the `Function App=>Settings=>Environment variables`:

**Keyvault Reference:**

```
@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://kpkvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/<secretname>/<SecretVersion>)
```

[image]

- Able to add the reference successfully:

[image]

Comment: It is very helpful, but I got stuck at the `I have assigned below Roles to the key vault:`. I don't understand where it is. It's supposed to be a configuration of the KV, right? Is it to be found somehow under the `Access control (IAM)`?

Comment: OK... I think I got it - you meant that I have to assign these roles to *myself* (i.e., my user) in the KV. Now it works! I am still a little puzzled where in these steps I actually grant access to the function app to access the KV.

Comment: It's addressed in 5th step.

Comment: Why isn't it enough to grant the app a "reader" permissions? Seems like it has to have admin one.

Comment: As mentioned in the [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/rbac-guide?tabs=azure-cli#azure-built-in-roles-for-key-vault-data-plane-operations), Reader role works for the key vaults which uses Azure RBAC. But sometimes, it cannot read sensitive values i.e., secret contents or key material.